# Populating field from related records on AGOL

Tags: arcgis-online, relates, arcade

I have a layer I would like to visualize based on related records. I understand this cannot be done directly in ArcGIS Online based on this article: [Visualize data from related records using Arcade](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/visualizing-data-from-related-records-using-arcade/). I would like to just periodically run Field Calculator in ArcGIS Pro to update a few fields to get the count of the number of related records per feature and some attributes from the most recent record. If I try to run an Arcade expression similar to what's mentioned in the article I get an error. Here I try to get the latest attribute distance.

```
var relatedrecords = FeatureSetByRelationshipName($feature, "Pipe_Inspection");
var latestRecord = First(OrderBy(relatedrecords, "inspectdt"))
return latestRecord.distance
```

Error received is:

> Invalid expression.
> Error on line 2.
> Expected feature set

I'm not sure why the function is not returning a featureset. How can I troubleshoot this? I also cannot use the AGOL Field Calculator since the layer has sync enabled, which disables Arcade.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you aren't using the Joined Feature Layer View option? This would simplify your workflow, eliminate the need to run periodic calculations, and allow you to symbolize on however many of the related fields you want to join to the layer.

Comment: I suppose the reason is because I didn't know that was a thing. I will give that a shot!

Comment: This did work well, thanks for the tip! That solved my overall problem. I guess I will leave it for an answer tot he Arcade question specifically, especially since it is straight from an ESRI post, I'd like to understand why the Arcade is throwing that error. This is a great functionality to know about though, thanks again!!

Comment: If you are working with hosted layers, it is a likely a limitation of the Arcade Execution profile. You would likely need to look into using a different access method like https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/portal_functions/#featuresetbyportalitem or transition to the ArcGIS API for Python where you can work with the data in dataframes.